# How to update my app prepared on beta iOS 14?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios14

Maybe it’s a stupid question but I launched my app in iOS on March so it’s my first time on a big iOS update...

So I’m preparing my app on iOS 14 using Beta 6 of Xcode implementing the new IDFA message for Google AdMob but I don’t know exactly what is the normal procedure for launching this new version. I mean, do I have to wait until the release of iOS 14 date? Or do you usually schedule the update on App Store Connect knowing the release date of the new iOS?

I’m a little lost because I don’t know even if I’ve to check if iOS 14 is installed on the user’s device prior launching the App Tracking Transparency authorization...

Any helps will be really welcomed!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve done your part, you tested with iOS 14 beta.
If you want to be more confident, you should also test your app with xcode 12 beta, to make sure it builts and archived successfully.

As for the app you currently have in the App Store, no action is required. Once Apple releases iOS 14 officially, you can then built it with the latest xcode 12 and submit an update.

But even if you don’t update your app, users will still be able to download and use it.

I hope this answers your question.